# Otimização/correção em "DbContext.SaveChanges()"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tendo em conta o seguinte cenário:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var allObjects = new List<MyObject>();
    var objects = myStaticClass.GetAllObjects();

    foreach (var myObject in allObjects)
        dbContext.MyObject.Add(myObject);

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    scope.Complete();
}
```

No *loop* tenho cerca de **250.000** registos a serem processados, ou seja, esses tantos a serem adicionados a um `DbSet` para posteriormente serem armazenados, de uma única vez, na base de dados através do `SaveChanges()` do `DbContext`.

O problema aqui é a quantidade de objetos a serem adicionados ao `DbSet`, que a certa altura provoca um **`System.OutOfMemoryException`** (atinge perto dos **2Gb** de memória ocupada), isto porque a arquitetura do processo é **x86**, algo que não me é possível alterar.

---

O que preciso, até urgentemente, é de uma solução para este caso, ou seja, preciso de armazenar os **250.000** registos mas tenho que evitar o **`System.OutOfMemoryException`** para deixar o processo terminar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com uma solução mais "crua", onde basicamente faço os `INSERT` diretamente na base de dados sem passar pelo **EF**:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var allObjects = myStaticClass.GetAllObjects();

    int count = allObjects.Count;
    bool split = count > 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        MyObject myObject = allObjects[i];

        sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO MyObjects(Id, Column1, Column2, Column3)");
        sb.AppendLine($"VALUES('{myObject.Id}', '{myObject.Column1}', '{myObject.Column2}', '{myObject.Column3}')");

        if ((split && i > 0 && (i % 100) == 0) || (i + 1) == count)
        {
            dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sb.ToString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }

    if (sb.Length > 0)
    {
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sb.ToString());
        sb = null;
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Cheguei à conclusão que o problema era mesmo o **EF**, que para além de aumentar o consumo de memória também prejudicava a performance de forma quase gradual.

Answer (score 1):

Desculpe-me você tinha razão existia uma solução mais simples e que não envolvesse contagem da memória usada:

```
foreach (var myObject in allObjects)
{
     try{

        dbContext.MyObject.Add(myObject);

     } catch (OutOfMemoryException){
        // Se der erro por falta de memória:
        // Salve as alterações já feita
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        // Força uma coleta de lixo imediata de todas as gerações.
        GC.Collect();
        // Refaz a última operação.
        dbContext.MyObject.Add(myObject);
     } catch (Exception){
       // tratamento para outros tipos de exceção
     }
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Olá @Augusto. Essa parece-me bem mais viável e código *friendly*. Obrigado. Será que poderia pelo menos retirar o voto negativo da minha questão?

Comment: Edite para eu possa retirar.